# Not able call to api from local development server ip address from ios

Tags: ios

**when i try to call an api from my development server it cannot work. it shows an error**.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the
>   server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170240b70 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.40/byker-api-server/webservices/braintree_client_token_generation.php,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.40/byker-api-server/webservices/braintree_client_token_generation.php,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

**this is the ip address i am calling http://192.168.1.40/byker-api-server/webservices/braintree_client_token_generation.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a local ip address. Check if your iOS device is connected to the same network, then try to type this address into your iOS Safari browser to be sure if it can connect to the server in general.